# I have installed autoFac and AutoFac.Mvc5 both but RegisterControllers() method is not Available

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, dependencies, autofac, autofac-configuration

[here is screenshot of IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIKel.png)
I have installed autofac and autofac.mvc5 both packages but RegisterControllers() method is not available and also "Using AutoFac.Integeration.Mvc" Namespace not accessible and showing error.

here is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using OdoFood.Data.Services;
using System.Reflection;
using Autofac;
using Autofac.Integration.Mvc;

namespace OdoFood.Web
{
    public class ContainerConfig
    {
        internal static void RegisterContainer()
        {
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterController(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
            
            
        }

       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code...

```cs
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterController(typeof(MvcApplication).Assembly);
```

...says `RegisterController` (singular) not `RegisterControllers` (plural). Add an `s` on the end of that.

Comment: I've tried it with "RegistredControllers" too but the result is the same.

Comment: Then you haven't provided enough information to troubleshoot. Given the [working examples](https://github.com/autofac/Examples/blob/548897fd8e8e86583d99c118829429db0a0b5de9/src/MvcExample/Global.asax.cs?_pjax=%23js-repo-pjax-container%2C%20div%5Bitemtype%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2FSoftwareSourceCode%22%5D%20main%2C%20%5Bdata-pjax-container%5D#L50) show this code as fine and it does compile, and your posted example is incorrect, all we can do is go off that posted incorrect code.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and these steps solved the problem:

1. Uninstall all Autofac libraries
2. Install Autofac
3. Install Autofac.Mvc5